# Jest + knex 'Unable to acquire a connection' during integration tests (sequelize works fine)

Tags: express, jestjs, sequelize.js, connection-string, knex.js

I have both sequelize and knex in my project (node.js, express, using TypeScript). Just introduced knex as I don't like sequelize and just want a light-weight query builder.

In non-test environments both sequelize and knex work fine, however when running tests (using jest) knex is, apparently, not able to connect to the database. They both use the same databaseUrl, though sequelize has a few more options configured. When running my tests under jest I can't figure out why I am getting

> Error: Unable to acquire a connection\n    at
> Client_PG.acquireConnection

When NODE_ENV is set to 'test', the express app uses a postgres database on my local machine.

Here is the configuration code

```
const _sqlz = new Sequelize(
  config.dbConString,
  {
    logging: config.nodeEnv === 'test' ? false : false,
    define: { freezeTableName: true },
    dialect: 'postgres',
    ...config.sslDB === 'true'
      ? {
          dialectOptions: {
            ssl: {
              require: true,
              rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
          }
        }
      : {}
  }
);

const knexConfig = {
  client: 'postgres',
  connection: config.dbConString,
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 15
  }
};

const _knex = knex(knexConfig)
```

When running jest it will give me a `Unable to acquire a connection` when trying to execute a simple knex query like so

```
await _knex('myTable').select('*');
```

To figure out what's happening I configured things such that jest would use the same test database when I set my node environment to be development, i.e. `NODE_ENV=development`. Interestingly now that development and test point to the same local database, if I run jest, it still gives me the same error about not being able to acquire a connection. So me setting `NODE_ENV=test` in of itself is not the issue. If I run the app (`npm run start`) while pointing to my local database, knex works fine, which leads me to think something about jest + knex isn't meshing well. jest + sequelize is working fine.

I tried playing around with the SSL settings but to no avail (I did see some knex + heroku blog posts needing ssl to be explicitly set), e.g.:

```
const knexConfig = {
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    connectionString: config.databaseUrl,
    ssl: {
      require: true,
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 15
  }
};
```

Hoping someone with more experience might have some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: i have used Jest+Knex in the past, this article summarize it pretty well = https://www.taniarascia.com/integration-testing-with-jest-typescript-objection/, there's many details to look, could you share a github repo with the minimal code to reproduce the error?

Comment: did you run your tests in band?

Comment: i can try and reproduce it and share that, though it will take a little bit of time. 
Note, I don't use objection.ts or have migration or seed files - I only use knex as a query builder

Comment: Check if https://github.com/felixmosh/knex-mock-client can help you :]

Comment: @oieduardorabelo Got it working. I noticed 2 things. (i) If I create a new knex connection directly in the test file and use that it works. (ii) Looking at the code in that article I see, on line 15 in the integration tests section, they call Model.knex(knex). That gave me an idea... today I access knex inside my production code by calling config.knex (the knex instead lives on the config object which is created somewhere in the app startup at the same time as sequelize). In my test code, in beforeAll, I create a new instance of knex and assign config.knex to it. Feels like a hack but works

Comment: I don't know why the knex instance needs to be created in the jest test environment, interested to hear ideas. Happy I have a solution/workaround

Comment: actually i meant to say beforeEach, not beforeAll. Having it in beforeAll doesn't work if multiple tests take a code path which results in a knex query invocation